# Switch maven from remote project dependency to local

Tags: maven

I have such a pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
<!--...-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mynamespace</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.149-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
<!--...-->
```

I have cloned this project to local directory D:/framework and made some changes. Now I want maven use fresh changes from local repository. How could I manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be as simple as doing a `mvn clean install` from the source directory of your dependency. The dependency will then be installed into your local repository.

When you then build your project, it will look in your local repository and use the version it finds there.

If you're trying to develop on both projects within a single IDE, then it should be even simpler, and you should see changes live - In Eclipse, you need to turn on local workspace resolution (Right Click on your project -> Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution)

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) can do it for you: 
[image: eclipse]